# Write a custom task with arguments in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, continuous-deployment

I want to write a script for following task in gradle. In IDE I run the task following way. [image] When I want to add a custom task in the build.gradle file for the same. I wrote following script but it is giving me `no such property: Classes for class: org.gradle.api.Project` error . How to write the task I have in the screenshot using a custom script in gradle? Thank you.

```
task h2Continuous(type: Classes) {
    args "--continuous"
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just call from CMD `gradle classes -t` ?

Comment: Eventually I want to combine two tasks in this one script so that when - one task is run it starts up two tasks.

Comment: to make a task that runs two tasks, you simply make an "empty" ad-hoc task that is configured to `dependsOn` the two other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a Task type `Classes`.  `classes` (lowercase) is a ad hoc declared task of the Java plugin, but not a unique Task type.  It is an ad hoc task which wraps (via dependsOn) compileJava and processResources tasks.  `compileJava` *is* a unique task type: JavaCompile.

If you are truly concerned with only java compilation, you could type your task as a JavaCompile task.  There are multiple ways you could add in the processResources, if you really wanted your task to emulate the Java plugin's `classes` task.

Comment: on this link https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html the classes is of type `Task` but do you know how to add arguments to a task.

Comment: you don't "call" a task, so you don't really provide arguments to a task.  You need to clarify what kind of args you're trying to add.  I think the "--abcd" kind of args are not task args but arguments to the entire gradle command (which may invoke multiple tasks).  If you are trying to provide a shortcut to run a specific gradle command with specific gradle arguments, you could just make script to run gradle with all passed-in arguments and one the hardcoded task name and hardcoded gradle argument.  If you want the gradle arguments to apply to all tasks, you could modify your gradlew script.

Comment: "If you are trying to provide a shortcut to run a specific gradle command with specific gradle arguments, you could just make script to run gradle with all passed-in arguments and one the hardcoded task name and hardcoded gradle argument" - how to do this - can you add it in your answer?

Comment: it would be OS-specific script: Windows/Linux/Unix.  I'm not a great scripter.